# Overriding antd component style for just one component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

Working with `antd` components, if you have an `Alert` component, inside there is a tooltip that is given the styling through ​`ant-alert-icon`​ class. So, if we need to override the Tooltip color, you can have in your stylesheet a class to override the values. For example:

```
ant-alert-info {
  .ant-alert-icon {
    color: #3d6de7 !important;
  }
}
```

However, this will apply the color #3d6de7 to all Alerts type `Info`. How can I apply a different color to just one specific Alert type `Info` while keeping the styling above for the remaining Alert type `Info` components? Is this possible? What are the alternatives to doing something similar?

I am able to change the background of the `Alert` using the style field as follows:

```
 <Alert
    description={}
    type="info"
    showIcon
    style={!props.alert ? { backgroundColor: "#F4F0F0"} : { backgroundColor: "#fff2f0", border: "#ffccc7" }} 
  />
```

However, I have not been able to change the Tooltip color.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an additional className like `ant-alert-info-custom` this way:

```js
<Alert
   description={}
   type="info"
   showIcon
   className="ant-alert-info-custom ant-alert-info-custom-with-red-icon"
/>
```

And use it like this:

```scss
.ant-alert-info.ant-alert-info-custom {
  // some shared styles by all custom alerts
  .ant-alert-icon {
    color: #3d6de7 !important;
  }
  // specific style for red icon
  &.ant-alert-info-custom-with-red-icon{
    .ant-alert-icon {
      color: red!important;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @yousoumar, it is very clean the solution. Can be possible to have additional classes overriding ant-alert-icon? I mean, to have additional classes besides blue color in your example above? wondering if there is a limit to overwrite the icon or can override with more colors? Have the impression `ant-alert-info-overwritten` is already exposed by antd and we can use it once. Is this a fair assumption?

Comment: You are welcome! I used `ant-alert-info-overwritten` as it's the first thing that came to my mind. You can name it as you want. And you can add as many colors as you want with different classNames. I just edited my answer. Take a look please.

Comment: worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot @yousoumar. One more question related, I have the tooltip height to 1em. I see this value coming from class `anticon anticon-info-circle ant-alert-icon`. I added height to 2 em in the above example where you included red as color, but did not get the change in position for tooltip. Should not suffice to include hight in the `ant-alert-icon` you showed?

Comment: I think my confussion is in the following, when we create a class with atributes, we can assign the class to a div for instance and the attributes would be applied. However, in an antd component, how can I differentiate between changing the tooltip or the message or the border of the alert. How can I refer to each of these sub-components in the Alert.

Comment: My pleasure @JohnBarton! After adding your classame name say `ant-alert-info-custom-with-red-icon`, anyting that's within that `Alert` can be acces trough CSS as normal HTML. The only difference here is that you need to use the inspection tool to see what its contains. Other than that if something not working, it could be a sepecifiaction issue or you are not targetting the correct element. See [here](https://codepen.io/yousoumar/pen/MWXePXp) I'm able to change the height.

Comment: Could be fair to assume this? We need the custom class `ant-alert-info.ant-alert-info-custom-one`  in order to add the elements of the Alert we want to modify. In this case, `ant-alert-icon` and `svg` are classes that belong to Alert antd.

Comment: Yes, everything inside `.ant-alert-info.ant-alert-info-custom-one` is from Ant. You need this custom classe because you don’t want to impact all Ant Alert by accessing just `ant-alert-info`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you can do this:

```
<ConfigProvider csp={{ nonce: 'YourNonceCode' }}>
 <Button>My Button</Button>
</ConfigProvider>
```

I think you can use `ConfigProvider` to overwrite Antdesign styles. Check out the link for more info:
[ConfigProvider](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/).

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. Please see [answer].